# Joining Dataframe performance in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining two dataframes which are reading csv files from s3 and joining them using **`df.join`** it is taking 9 mins to complete when using default `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (200).

When I change `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to 10, It is still taking almost the same time.

Is there any way to improve the performance of the same job.

Also, How to dynamically decide the value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` in a production scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the most effective ways to speed up the spark joins is to minimize the number of elements in each data frame; for example, you could apply as many filters as possible on data frames before join them. Another way is to use the broadcast data frame approach for smaller data frames (keep in mind that broadcast data frames must be magnitude smaller than others). For more details, you can use the following tips on spark join optimization:

[databricks presentation on optimizing apache-spark SQL joins](https://databricks.com/session/optimizing-apache-spark-sql-joins)

[Performance Tuning of apache-spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html)